# Custom TCDL tag

Tags: 2013, tcdl

On my current project we need to implement custom `TCDL` tag.
The purpose of the tag is to recognize the device that is used (mobile, tablet, desktop) and to return the content for that device.
We implemented the `com.tridion.tcdl.TagRenderer` interface in our code but I cannot see any method that will give me current request so I can check the device that is used.

Is this solution even possible with `TCDL` tags?

Comment: You need to use the Claimstore to read the Device claim from the Context Engine cartridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you won't have access to the Request object itself, you should indeed look at the information available in the claimstore. There's a lot of info in there. As Nick suggests, if you have SDL Mobile then just read the device properties from the claims it populates.

Loads of info and examples if you google for "Ambient Data Framework".